# Problem on list in custom command using adjustbox

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a problem, that seems to be quite common : code expansion.

I have declared a command, that use an other command that use adjustbox.
So far so good, until I need to pass to the first command a itemsize as an argument.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
Test

\newcommand{\compVProMargin}[1]{
    \adjustbox{margin=10mm 0 0 0}{
    #1
    }
}
\newcommand{\compVPro}[2]{
    \compVProMargin{
        First arg : #1
    }\\
    \compVProMargin{
        \textbf{Second arg} : #2
    }\\
}

\section{This works ok}
\compVPro{
    first argument, no code, works ok
}{
    second argument, no code works ok too
}


\section{This doen't works}
\compVPro{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
    \end{itemize}
}{
    foo
}
\end{document}
```

I think I have to use commands like \expandafter and such, but I really don't manage to understand where to put it to make it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe useful http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11357

Comment: Ok, but isn't a solution for list only ? couldn't it happen on other kind of usage ?

Comment: Yes it is. But you could put itemes into list. Just an idea.

Comment: The problem is not expansion but the box. Why do you use \adjustbox here?